# linear mixed model or non-linear mixed model

Tags: mixed-model, linear, medicine

I´m in the medical field and study biomarkers. I study a biomarker that after a worsening of symptom, first increase and then decrease. It´s almost like the kinetics of blood-glucose after you eat. I have several measurements longitudinally. I have covariates (age for example) and I want to compare two groups. I was thinking of linear mixed model, but one assumption is that it must be linearly related to the random factor..? In this case, the random factor are the time-points.
Can linear mixed model be used, or do I have to use some other more advanced model; mixed additive /non-linear model?
Sincerely
/Magnus

Comment: Only use the LMM if you have a continuous outcome, assumed to follow a normal distribution and that has a linear relationship. I'm not very experienced in the field of biomarkers, but I heard that for modelling (pharmaco)kinetics, non-linear mixed models are surely advised to be used and they might help you out to model these advanced trends!

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Please edit the question to say more about how the data are collected (e.g., how many measurements per individual over what period of time, what range the measurements cover, are there multiple sets of measurements on the same individual) and exactly what you want to compare between the two groups. If you do a mixed model the "random effect" should _not_ be the time points, but rather the individuals with multiple measurements. You can often model non-linear trajectories with models that are linear _in the parameters_, but the best approach depends on these details.